# stop watch problem in android

Tags: android

i creating for stopwatch with start,stop i use following code it started but not stop. please help me.
my code:

```
public class StopWatch2 extends Activity implements Runnable{

// text view influenced by the Thread
private TextView threadModifiedText;
int time=0;
Button b1,b2,b3;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
Thread currentThread = new Thread(this);
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.stopwatch);

    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    threadModifiedText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View view) 
        {
            currentThread.start();
        }

    });     
    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View view) 
        {
            currentThread.stop();
        }

    });               
}

//Method you must override to control what the Thread is doing
@Override
public void run(){
    try {
        while(true){
            currentThread.sleep(1000, 0);
            threadHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
        // signaling things to the outside world goes like this  

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }   
} 
private Handler threadHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        time++;
        threadModifiedText.setText(""+time);
    }
};
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You should use a class level variable `boolean shouldRun = true ;`
in your `run()` method `while` should be used like this way

```
while(shouldRun)
{
 //implementation
}
```

and in your `b2.onClickListener()` change `shouldRun = false;`

**Edit:**
For `suspend` and `resume` you can change the value of `shouldRun` to `shouldRun = true;` in the listener for resume button. Remember that when you `stop` the updates you should reset the `time` also. and in `suspend` the `time` should be remain same.

Comment: thanks it works and tried for pause and resume i use pause for Thread.suspend() and resume i use Thread.resume(); Thread.resume() is not resume the work. how to do that please...

Comment: sorry for delay i tried as follows for start/resume: 
               if(currentThread.getState()==Thread.State.NEW){
                currentThread.start();


                Log.e("after",""+currentThread.getState());
                 shouldRun = true;
                b1.setText("pause");
               }
               else{
                 shouldRun = true;
                 b1.setText("pause");
               }

 start again after pause not run the run method please...

Comment: thanks it works i add a while like:
while(true){
  while(shouldRun){
     .....
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

I implemented stopwatch for rotational puzzles solving time measurements and I have approached it somewhat differently.

- For time measurements I use Handler object that triggers after DISPLAY_UPDATE_TIMEOUT. It is time after which you update display about time elapsed.

To start counting I use:

```
mLastStartTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
mRepetitiveTimeoutHandler.postDelayed(processWatchTimer, DISPLAY_UPDATE_TIMEOUT);
```

and to stop it

```
mRepetitiveTimeoutHandler.removeCallbacks(processWatchTimer);
mStartStopElapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - mLastStartTimestamp ;
updateTimeDisplay();
```

On each trigger of the handler I do the following:

```
private Runnable processWatchTimer = new Runnable()
{
    public void run() 
    {
        mRepetitiveTimeoutHandler.postDelayed(processWatchTimer, DISPLAY_UPDATE_TIMEOUT);
        updateTimeDisplay();            
    }
};
```